# QGIS Python script crash when looping many times (memory problem?)

Tags: pyqgis, loop, iteration, memory

I'm having trouble with a part of a Python code that does many iterations (about 5000).

The problem found is that the program crashes, it returns an error (sometimes memory error, other times all QGI windows close) and then the whole PC crashes for a few moments. It is not a problem with the code because the program stops at different points every time even if the inputs are the same. If I do a test with a few iterations (200/300) I have no problem.

It would seem to be a memory and file management problem, I suppose of temporary files that QGIS generates. The ram is high, but it looks ok to me.

Below just a sample code.

Do you have any advice? Is there a way to clear the memory with each iteration? I'm a beginner

```
    for step in range (1,5000):
        outputs={}
        feedback.setProgressText('Step: {} of {}.'.format(step,'5000'))
        
        #---->select everytime the same input point by query just to test the iteration
        
        query = 'select *,geometry from input1 where id_nodo=1' # test over the same point
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT_DATASOURCES': parameters['pointsinput'],
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_CRS': None,
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_FIELD': '',
            'INPUT_GEOMETRY_TYPE': 0,  
            'INPUT_QUERY': query,
            'INPUT_UID_FIELD': '',
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['SelectOnePointInput'] = processing.run('qgis:executesql', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(1)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Buffer 9 km
        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'DISTANCE': 150,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,  
            'INPUT': outputs['SelectOnePointInput']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,  
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Buffer9Km'] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(2)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Clip 9km graph2
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['graph2'],
            'OVERLAY': outputs['Buffer9Km']['OUTPUT'],
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Clip9kmGraph2'] = processing.run('native:clip', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(3)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # extract points 2
        alg_params = {
            'INPUT': parameters['points2'],
            'INTERSECT': outputs['Buffer9Km']['OUTPUT'],
            'PREDICATE': [0],  
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['ExtractPoints2'] = processing.run('native:extractbylocation', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)

        feedback.setCurrentStep(4)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}
        #feedback.pushInfo('95')
        # Buffer 15 km 
        alg_params = {
            'DISSOLVE': False,
            'DISTANCE': 15000,
            'END_CAP_STYLE': 0,  
            'INPUT': outputs['SelectOnePointInput']['OUTPUT'],
            'JOIN_STYLE': 0,  
            'MITER_LIMIT': 2,
            'SEGMENTS': 5,
            'OUTPUT': QgsProcessing.TEMPORARY_OUTPUT
        }
        outputs['Buffer15Km'] = processing.run('native:buffer', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        #feedback.pushInfo('108')
       
        feedback.setCurrentStep(5)
        if feedback.isCanceled():
            return {}

        # Snap points2
        alg_params = {
            'BEHAVIOR': 2,  
            'INPUT': outputs['ExtractPoints2']['OUTPUT'],
            'REFERENCE_LAYER': outputs['Clip9kmGraph2']['OUTPUT'],
            'TOLERANCE': 50,
            'OUTPUT': 'memory:'
        }
        #outputs['SnapPoints2'] = processing.run('native:snapgeometries', alg_params, context=context, feedback=feedback, is_child_algorithm=True)
        lyr_snap_point2=processing.run('native:snapgeometries',alg_params,  context=context)['OUTPUT']
        features_snap_point2 =  lyr_snap_point2.getFeatures()
        if step==1:
            sink_snap_point2, dest_snap_point2 = self.parameterAsSink(parameters,'SnapPoints2',context,lyr_snap_point2.fields(),lyr_snap_point2.wkbType(),lyr_snap_point2.sourceCrs())
                        
        for  feature_snap_point2 in features_snap_point2:
            sink_snap_point2.addFeature(feature_snap_point2, QgsFeatureSink.FastInsert)
            
            
        del outputs
    return {}
```

the error that sometimes (not always) appears:

```
p><b>virtual:</b> Query execution error on CREATE TEMP VIEW _tview AS select *,geometry from input1 where id_nodo=1: 7 - out of memory
Execution failed after 508.15 secondi
```